# The best way to edit slider images and links

Tags: php, database, image, laravel, sliders

I have a slider in the index page, which has 3 pictures and this pictures has links. What is the best way to change pictures and links: make db table sliders:

```
id
pic
link
```

and work with it, or  make in config->settings.php something like this:

```
<?php
return [
        'new_products_count' => 6,
        'popular_products_count' => 6,
        'paginate' => 20,
        'admin_paginate' => 10,
        'slider'=>[
                   1=>['img'=>'1.jpg','link'=>'www1'],
                   2=>['img'=>'2.jpg','link'=>'www2'],
                   3=>['img'=>'3.jpg','link'=>'www3']
                   ]
       ];
```

and work with it like this:

```
Config::set('settings.slider[1]['img']=>'newimg.jpg')
Config::set('settings.slider[1]['link']=>'newWWW')
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be safer to keep in the database for a couple of reasons.

1- If you cache your configuration, it may sometimes behave like a buggy application. I mean after changing an image and coming back, you may see the previous image displaying again. Because what you change at runtime is not persisted. Try to update a config option, e.g:

```
config(['database.connections.sqlite.driver' => 'fake']);
```

Then go check the file. tadaaa... the file didn't change.

2- You database is unlimited. YOu can add an infinite number of images (links) with much more options. Of course, you can also pass options to `config()` but using Eloquent or Query builder is more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Gonna make table ;)